# Analyzing Worst Case Performance of Quicksort by Substitution Method

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, quicksort, recurrence

I am trying to solve the reccurence of the quicksort algorithm by the substitution method:

[image: formula]

I can not find any way to proof that this will lead to [image: formula]. What further steps do I have to make to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worst case of quicksort is when you choose a pivot element which is the minimum or maximum element from the array, so that all remaining elements go to one side of the partition, and the other side of the partition is empty. In this case, the non-empty partition has a size of (n - 1), and it takes linear time (kn for some constant k > 0) to do the partitioning itself, so the recurrence relation is

> T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(0) + kn

If we guess that T(n) = an² + bn + c for some constants a, b, c, then we can substitute:

> an² + bn + c = [ a(n - 1)² + b(n - 1) + c ] + [ c ] + kn

where the two square-bracketed terms are T(n - 1) and T(0) respectively. By expanding the brackets and equating coefficients, we get

> an² = an²
>
> bn = -2an + bn + kn
>
> c = a - b + 2c

It follows that there is a family of solutions, parameterised by c = T(0), where a = k/2 and b = k/2 + c. This family of solutions can be written exactly as

> T(n) = (k/2) n² + (k/2 + c) n + c

which is not just O(n²), but Ө(n²), meaning the running time is a quadratic function, not merely bounded above by a quadratic function. Note that the actual value of c doesn't change the asymptotic behaviour of the function, so long as k > 0 (i.e. the partitioning step does take a positive amount of time).

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my question, the continuation of the previous equation is,

[image: formula]

This is true if

[image: formula]